# Check if props in vue.js component template exists

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

After tried many variations, I don't know how to properly style a component's slot or partial code within `<template></template>` section.

Is there a way to check if props `<counter :recent="true"></counter>` from parent level exists, so in a `Counter.vue` in section `<template></template>` i would show a special html markup for it ?

**=== UPDATED ===**

```js
Vue.component('counter', {
 template: `
<span class="counter" :number="21" v-text="number">
 <span v-if="recent">
   since VARTIME
  </span>
</span>
  `,
  data: function(){
   return{
     count: this.number + 1
    }
  },
  props: {
   number: Number,
    recent: {
     type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
   
  },
  created(){
   if( this.recent === true ){
     console.log('mounted recent true');
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
 el: "#app",
  
  data: {
   count: ''
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">

  <counter :number="20" :recent="true"></counter>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the default value for the `recent` will be `false` and if the `recent` is passed from the `parent` it will get set in the child.

Just use the detailed props definition as [mentioned here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Prop-Validation).

**Remove the `v-text="number"` as it overrides the internal content of the span and therefore the v-if will never executes.**

This is a working example

```js
Vue.component('counter', {
  template: `
    <span class="counter" :number="21">
      <span v-if="recent"> since VARTIME </span>
    </span>
  `,
  data: function() {
    return {
        count: this.number + 1    
    }
  },
  props: {
    number: Number,
    recent: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  },
  computed: {},
  created() {
    if ( this.recent === true ) {
        console.log('mounted recent true');
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    count: ''
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">

  <counter :number="20" :recent="true"></counter>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a condition class binding, that you eventually style from css/sass/stylus/less.

This can be done as follows:

```
<template>
    <span class="counter" v-text="count" :class="{ cssClassName: recent}">
        <slot></slot>
        <span v-if="recent">
            since VAR_DATETIME <i class="fa fa-refresh" @click="updateList"></i>
        </span>
    </span>
</template>
```

Notice that vuejs will automatically [combine multiple class declarations on the same element without problems, as described in the manual](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax).

Comment: This will render a `span` section anyway, if I will use css conditional styling ?